# Magento - PDF preflight

Tags: magento2, pdf, 3rd-party-library

I need to programm a extension that checks a PDF our customer uploads for things like the right format (in terms of size for example 210 x 297 mm) or if there is 3 mm bleed on the PDF.

I really dont know how to handle this, I would need to extend magento with some external libarys.

Can someone help me out, how would you guys get something like this to work?

Comment: This extension allows customer uploading the Pdf?

Comment: Yes exactly,  the customer uploads the PDF and we need to check it. ( if it is in the required format for example)

Comment: For example, check the allowed type: only Pdf type?

Comment: No, format in terms of size, like 210 x 297 mm

Comment: Please, update your question more details.